# Can I install and run Titanfall without a disc?

Tags: pc, titanfall

I plan on buying Titanfall, but I'm not too keen on the humongous download size.

If I were to buy the PC disc of the game, could I install the game and run it without a disc?

Comment: Titanfall will probably need Origin to play anyway, this means that the disc will probably just install the game just like downloaded from origin. And you won't need the disc afterwards to play, it is the same for steam.

Comment: Awesome! I knew it requires origin but just wanted to be sure that I can use it without a CD. I don't have a CD drive (that fits in my CD bay) so when I need to use a CD, I just hot patch it into a sata port in my pc and just have it sitting on the floor outside the case. I don't mind doing that to install games, but I'd rather not doing it while playing the game haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To play Titanfall all you need is the EA platform **Origin**. If you buy a boxed copy of Titanfall it will come with a Serial-Number which you have to bind to your Origin Account. From this moment on you don't need your DVD anymore.

In other words: Buying the game as DVD will enable you to install it from DVD (so you don't have to download) but besides that there is **no difference** from buying a digital copy, meaning you can play it without the DVD anytime.